# error-waiting-for-container-eof-windows-docker

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

Esta es mi primera pregunta asi que cualquier, consejo/correccion es bienvenido.

Estoy corriendo docker en windows. **(docker-compose run miapp)**

Pasado el tiempo, a veces un par de horas, otras veces dias

El contenedor termina con el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
# time="2020-10-07T15:16:19-03:00" level=error msg="error waiting for container: EOF"
```

Cuando intento correrlo nuevamente, recibo el siguiente error:

```
ERROR: open \\.\pipe\docker_engine_linux: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Y tengo que reiniciar el servicio de docker, y correr el contenedor nuevamente, pero luego de un tiempo el mismo escenario se repite...

Esto es realmente molesto, no entiendo si se cierra por inactividad o cual es la verdadera causa y como impedir que esto ocurra.

Comment: Eso tiene toda la pinta de ser un *bug* en Docker ...

Comment: que mal che, vos que decis creo el ticket

Comment: Hola @AlejandroKaspar, ayudaría que cuentes que tiene tu dockerfile o docker-compose.yml. Si podes copiarlos mejor.